# The Big red X in my C# windows application

Tags: c#, picturebox, bmp

My grogram:
1.recieve the **qrcode **from scanner.
2.query **coordinate data** from mysql database by **qrcode **
3.draw circle in the picturebox with **coordinate data**

But there is a error: the red x often appear, I've ever not found the solution.
[image: red X like this]

I used this method, but it isn't useful.

```
pb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate
{
    pb.Image = bmp;
}));
```

So, is ther any method for it
Thanks!!!

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/205233)

Comment: I bet the image is a fallback in case drawing the circle fails. If you cannot provide a [mcve] of your code reproducing the problem, nobody here can help you.